# How can I search two columns (one of which only appears in a few records)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am performing a search on the following 2 columns of a document: **name** and **displayName**. However, only a few records have **displayName** column. When a record has both, I want to search both fields (name and displayName) for the possible match. Otherwise, if the record doesn't have the column **displayName**, I just want to search **name** instead. So I thought I'd do an **OR**. This however will only search fields that have both columns - although I want to search all records.

How can I update the query to achieve the above? Here's what I tried:

```
function search(search) {
  return this.find({ $or: [
      {"displayName" : {"$regex" : ".*"+ search +".*", "$options": "-i"}},
      {"name" : {"$regex" : ".*"+ search +".*", "$options": "-i"}}
  ]}).exec();
}
```

So on the query above, the logic tells me that if **displayName** column doesn't exist, the first check will return **false** so it will then search **name** which will return true/false based on the match. I am obviously missing something here because even if the second check would be true, the overall result comes out false (which is more like AND behavior instead of OR).

Data Example:

```
{ id: 3, name: "John Steinbeck", displayName: "Steinbeck" }
{ id: 4, name: "John Lennon" }
{ id: 5, name: "Doe", displayName: "John" }
{ id: 5, name: "Harry Potter", displayName: "Harry" }
```

Search word:

```
john
```

Expected Result:

```
{ id: 3, name: "John Steinbeck", displayName: "Steinbeck" }
{ id: 4, name: "John Lennon" }
{ id: 5, name: "Doe", displayName: "John" }
```

**Later Edit**

This query does seem to work after all, the problem turned out to be the data and not the query. Human error. My apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

You've to different conditions:

- Both field exist and have the correct value
- Only name exist and have the correct value

use `$exist` and `$or`!

for example:

```
db.col.find({ $or: [ { name: {$regex : ".*John.*"}}, displayName: {$regex : ".*Steinbeck.*"}}, { name: "john", { displayName: { $exists: false } } } ] } )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see where the flaw in my logic would have been. I have adapted your answer to my example, but now I get 0 results back: { $or: [ 
    { "name": { $regex : ".*john.*", $options: '-i' }, "displayName": { $regex : ".*john.*", $options: '-i' } }, 
    { "name": { $regex : ".*john.*", $options: '-i' }, "displayName": { $exists: false } } 
] } - please note that I only have one search parameter (in the example above is "john")

Comment: @Toonsylvania your `displayname` is **Steinbeck** not **john**! :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, maybe I wasn't clear enough :) What I am looking for is to find **any records** that have **the key word** in **either one** of the 2 fields (name or displayName). If you look at the example I gave, one of the expected results is { id: 5, name: "Doe", displayName: "John" } which has john in displayName, not name. So john (which is the key word here) can be in either one of those columns (or both even)

Comment: Oh! So you don't even need that **$exist**! your condition is `name is "john"` or `displayName is "john"`! so this is your answer: `{ $or: [ { "name": { $regex : ".*john.*", $options: '-i' }}, {"displayName": { $regex : ".*john.*", $options: '-i' }} ] } `

Answer (score 0):

change your query:

```
db.getCollection('user').find({ $or: [
  {"name" : {$regex: "john", $options: "$i"}},
  {"displayName" : {$regex: "john", $options: "$i"}}]})
```